# Are the books written for blender 2.5 or 2.6 still useful for the latest blender 2.7 version?

Tags: versions

I know that latest blender will have more features and better perfomance, etc., but is there a big difference between 2.5, 2.6 & 2.7 that will cause trouble for me as a beginner?

Answer (score 11):

Whether or not you can use information for a old version depends on what you are comparing:

- Cycles came out in [2.61](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.61), so anything prior will be for the blender internal.
- The Python API has [changed](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_5/change_log.html) a fair bit since 2.5. So scripts, addons and python tutorials will most likely be incompatible.
- Many of the buttons may have sightly different places: example in [2.70](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.70) tabs for the toolbar came out.

In general anything written for 2.5 and up is still (more or less) relevant and use full now.

If you get stuck, or something is not where it was then, ask a new question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are. Big differences from 2.4 version, but from 2.5 things are only get better, more functions, more stability, improvements; but the basis are the same.